# DC Sitecore User Group: Sitecore Symposium Recap and Introducing SitecoreUML

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Thursday, 16 November 2017 *at 6:00pm*
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, 15 November 2017 *at 11:00pm*
- **Location:** Canvas, 1203 19th St NW, 3rd Floor, Washington, DC
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/DC-Sitecore-User-Group/events/244575639/)
- **Contact:** Dean Thrasher, Brent Pinkstaff, Ed Kapuscinski ([Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/DC-Sitecore-User-Group/))
- **Description:**

Join us for our Fall event which will feature in-depth Sitecore presentations and a chance to network with your peers from the DMV area. We will be discussing Sitecore Symposium 2017, plus an introduction to SitecoreUML.

**Agenda**

6:00pm Arrival & Networking
6:45pm Welcoming Remarks and Announcements
7:00pm Sitecore Symposium 2017 Recap (Dean Thrasher, Brent Pinkstaff, and Ed Kapuscinski)
7:40pm Introducing SitecoreUML (Zachary Kniebel) 
8:10pm Q&A
8:15pm Closing Remarks

**Sitecore Symposium 2017 Recap**

Can we say Sitecore 9? For those of you who were not able to attend the event in Las Vegas, we'll run through the big announcements, the new features, and what's to come for Sitecore. Even if you made it to the desert, we'll have you covered for reviewing some of the breakout sessions and news that you might have missed.

*SPEAKERS*

All three presenters are organizers of our group. Brent and Dean are both Solution Architects at EPAM Systems, and have been working with all things Sitecore for 13 years and 6 years respectively. Ed is a 3-time Sitecore MVP, and is the head of the Sitecore and CMS Practice at NTT Data.

**Introducing SitecoreUML**

SitecoreUML is a productivity tool that enables architects to create Sitecore templates directly from their UML diagrams, as well as export an existing Sitecore solution’s template architecture and generate UML diagrams from it. It's great for creating template architectures, auditing existing architectures, and creating detailed documentation that can be updated in just two clicks!

*SPEAKER*

Zachary is a Solution Architect in the Sitecore Competency at EPAM. A Sitecore evangelist, Zachary has been working with the Sitecore platform since 2012.